# How to adjust logo size according to image size using Imagemagick?

Tags: python, imagemagick, python-pptx

I am working on making PowerPoint (.pptx) files using `python-pptx` package so, what I am doing adding images in slides with joining these images with a watermark using `imagemagick`. so, the problem I am facing is that images on which I am adding watermarks are of different sizes. some are giving good results but some not. so I want that logo can easily adjust according to the image size.

Here is my code:

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches,Pt
from wand.image import Image

# function to add watermark using Imagemagick
 
def addwatermark(pic_path,i):
    with Image(filename = pic_path) as image:
        with Image(filename = 'nike_black.png') as water:
            print(water.width,water.height)
            water.resize(2000,600)
            with image.clone() as watermark:
                watermark.watermark(water,0.1,10,20)
                new_pic = "newimage{}.jpg".format(i)
                watermark.save(filename = new_pic)
    return new_pic


prs = Presentation()

for i in range(1,6):
    # Changing size of ppt acc. to sample ppt 
    prs.slide_width = Inches(16)
    prs.slide_height = Inches(9)


    blank_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6]
    slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)

    # Text box --1
    text_Box = slide.shapes.add_textbox(left = Inches(3),top = Inches(0),width = Inches(2),height = Inches(1))
    tf = text_Box.text_frame
    p = tf.add_paragraph()
    p.text = "Image With Nike LOGO"
    p.font.bold = True
    p.font.size = Pt(40)

    # Text box --2
    text_Box1 = slide.shapes.add_textbox(left = Inches(1),top = Inches(3),width = Inches(2),height = Inches(1))
    tf1 = text_Box.text_frame
    p = tf1.add_paragraph()
    run = p.add_run()
    p.level = 0
    run.text = "sample section {}".format(i)
    run.font.size = Pt(40)

    # Image height and width acc. to sample ppt
    height = Inches(5.21)
    width = Inches(4.17)

    pic  = slide.shapes.add_picture(addwatermark("image{}.jpg".format(i),i) ,left = Inches(1),top = Inches(2), height=height, width = width)

prs.save('new.pptx')
```

[image]

This is what I am expecting to generate from every image

[image]

but this slide is not giving the correct output.

Can anyone tell me how can I adjust a logo dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Simply execute this code

```
from io import FileIO
import os
from wand.image import Image
from pptx.util import Inches 
from pptx import Presentation     
  
def add_watermark()->FileIO:
    for file in os.listdir():
        if file.endswith('.jpg'):
        # Import the image
            with Image(filename =file) as image:
                
                # Import the watermark image
                width, height = image.size
                
                with Image(filename ='nike_black.png') as logo:
                    
                    # Resize the logo image according to the image size
                    logo.resize(width//3, height//8)
                    
                    # Clone the image in order to process
                    with image.clone() as watermark:
                        # Resize the watermark
                        watermark.watermark(logo)
                        # Save the image
                        watermark.save(filename ='watermarked_'+file)

def create_slide()->FileIO:
    # Creating presentation object
    root = Presentation()
    for file in os.listdir():
        if file.startswith('watermarked_'):
            # Creating slide layout
            first_slide_layout = root.slide_layouts[1] 
            slide = root.slides.add_slide(first_slide_layout)
            shapes = slide.shapes
            
            #Adding title or heading to the slide
            title_shape = shapes.title
            title_shape.text = f" Created By python-pptx for Watermarking "
            
            #Adding sub-title with border to the slide
            body_shape = shapes.placeholders[1]
            tf = body_shape.text_frame
            tf.text = f"This is a watermarked image of {file}"
                
            with open( f'{file}','rb') as watermarked_image:
                # Add the watermarked image to the slide
                slide.shapes.add_picture(watermarked_image ,Inches(1), Inches(3),
                        width=Inches(5), height=Inches(3))
                root.save("Output.pptx")
add_watermark()
create_slide()
```

**Note:-** Make sure that all your image files are in the same folder